# Update only one Field in FireStore with Fultter (Dart)

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data saved in my FireStore and I only need to update one field.

```
name: "Daniel",
lastname: "Pereira",
age: 25,
isLogged: false
```

I need only update **isLogged** to **true** for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only pass to updateDate a json like: **{"isLogged": true }**

```
final CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("profiles");
collectionReference.document("profile")
                .updateData({"isLogged": true})
                .whenComplete(() async {
              print("Completed");
            }).catchError((e) => print(e));
```

If are you using transaction you can do like:

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
          await transaction.update(
              collectionReference.document("profile"), {"isLogged": true});
        };
```

Hope this helps somebody! ;)

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, still updates the whole document.

Comment: Firebase doesn't allow updating single fields, it updates the entire document regardless. You can however set it to update only 1 field (but still be charged for an entire document update). Make sure to use the `Reference.set({}, SetOptions(merge: true))` to update only 1 field and retain other fields.